# Rendering a GitHub wiki on a GitHub Pages Jekyll site

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a repository with a wiki full of over 80 pages. I want to render an index of all the wiki pages on the Jekyll (GitHub Pages) site for the project, as well as render each page on the site using a custom layout, and using the styles of the rest of the site.

To do this, my first instinct was to use git submodules to include the pages from the wiki (which GitHub exposes as a git repo) in the Jekyll site's repo. But that's as far as I got: As far as I can tell, there is nowhere that Jekyll will accept markdown files that don't conform as a post. They aren't named with a date, and they don't have any frontmatter, so Jekyll just ignores them.

To get around this, I would normally just write a plugin to do what I wanted. But because the site is hosted on GitHub pages, it won't allow any plugins that I create.

So, I really don't know how to proceed. Is it even possible without custom plugins?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is :

1. download my [plugin](https://github.com/djacquel/WikiToJekyll)
2. read the docs
3. install and rake
4. drink a beer

What the raketask/plugin are doing once installed and configured (5 minutes) :

1. `rake wikisub` add a git submodule pointing to your wiki. Must be a public wiki but can be on another repository
2. copy and transform downloaded wiki pages as markdown with yaml front matter
3. build Jekyll, then the plugin intercept wiki pages links conversion to transform them as Jekyll links
4. order pizzas

For now the only problem (or not) is that Kramdown doesn't do well with Github markdown. You have to switch to redcarpet.

Two other tasks are available :

- `rake wikibuild` : rebuild wiki pages
- `rake wiki` : synch wiki page, build and optionally push change to Jekyll repository

Et hop!

Comment: That a very nice and detailed response. I had something similar in mind but I was too lazy to write something like that :)
One thing that would probably also need to be addressed are the internal links between wiki pages(if there are any), which might need to be changed to point to the pages on the site instead of the pages on github (I guess this depends if links are absolute or relative and if the main structure of page is similar to that one on the github).

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek you right I've missed this point. This can be a good code Kata for you ;-)  

`require "kramdown"`  

then something like  

`kDoc = Kramdown::Document.new(fileContent)`   

but, for now I can't get the parser.parse return the parser::link_defs collection for wiki pages at all.
Just in case the repository is here : https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllTest

Comment: Just so I understand, I would manually run a script that would pull down the new changes, copy the files to a different folder, and then add the frontmatter to each of them (and maybe fix links)?

Comment: @WasabiFan manually or with a cron job on a machine. And it will do the magic !

Comment: OK; thanks! I'll wait a bit before accepting to make sure that there aren't any more answers, but my guess is that this is the only/best option.

Comment: You can also include this rake task inside your generate task. So every time you generate the page this procedure will run. But it might take a while then.

Comment: Note that if no update is necessary, the rake task just stops.  
But, maybe we can combine the rake task with a Generator plugin to deal with the links transformation problem ? Will we put a bounty on this ? I nearly do !

Comment: Everything is being generated correctly (aside from the links, which I'll work on later). The files are being generated in `wiki/page name/index.html`, which works, but doesn't seem to be how it is happening in your sample repo. But using a loop to iterate over `site.pages` is returning no results. Any ideas?

Comment: @MitjaBezenšek I've finished my code Kata. See the edited answer.

Comment: 3 and a half years later, this is still working without a flaw.

Comment: As of July 31 2020, the link's dead.